# "Borrow Computer"/"Log in to VM" button on Windows Login screen?

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtual-machine

My last two workplaces have had a button on the Windows 7 login screen marked "Borrow" or "Use Another Computer".  This button allows any user to connect either to their own desktop machine, or to a VM, using the current physical machine as a terminal.  Is there any way I can get this functionality on my home PC?

Comment: I couldn't find much information online. It may be FactoryTalk View or some other software from Rockwell Automation. Or maybe it's some VM software. Is there any way you could contact them and ask? I'm actually kind of curious as well.